# merging .dll files with ILMerge failing to work

Tags: c#, dll, merge, ilmerge

First of all, I'm not sure if this is a problem with ILMerge or not, but I can't merge.dll files into my application. I tried this on the command line:

```
ilmerge /target:winexe /out:test.exe MyApp.exe lib1.dll lib2.dll lib3.dll
```

I got the following error, and I have no idea what it means:

There were errors reported in MyApp's metadata.
    The pdb associated with D:\C#\source\bin\ReleaseMyApp.exe is out of date.

I'm using the latest version by the way (2.10.526.0), but yeah I can't get this to work and I really need some help. What does the above error mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: Are there actually PDB files? How about compiling to Release version and removing any PDBs before calling `ilmerge`?

Comment: For ILMerge, I use it like `ilmerge /ndebug /target:winexe /out:test.exe app.exe lib1.dll lib2.dll`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The pdb associated with D:\C#\source\bin\ReleaseMyApp.exe is out of date.

Since you haven't explicitly said that you have checked the pdb and exes are in sync, I guess I'll ask the obvious question - Is there a pdb in the folder and have you checked the timestamps on the files?

As I understand it, if there is debug info available for the source files, then ilmerge will create debug information for the target and if the original is out-of-date, then it probably displays this error rather than generate incorrect information.

If you don't need the debug information, what happens if you delete the pdb files?

Comment: The pdb files were up to date, I just copied them after build suceeded. Also when I deleted it it seemed to work, although not surprising I received another error, fantastic.

"Unresolved assembly reference not allowed: Microsoft.mshtml..."

So after a bit of googling, I realized you need to specify the path to the .NET Framework version 4. So I did this:

ilmerge /targetplatform:v4,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 /out:test.exe MyApp.exe lib1.dll lib2.dll lib3.dll

I would expect it to work, but nope, I still get the same error.

Comment: Did you try using the config file to force ilmerge to run using Framework 4? See http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge-40-exe-config.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I expect this type metadata is being stored as a string, perhaps in explicit code, but perhaps via a "typeof" in an attribute.

You might try handling the AppDomain's TypeResolve event, detecting the type string that is failing and returning the Type you intend - this should work around the fact that it is now in a different assembly.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.typeresolve.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Would it help to try [.NETZ](http://madebits.com/netz/) instead of ILMerge?

Comment: Nope, because I tried that program and of course, it doesn't work.
I used: netz -s app.exe lib1.dll lib2.dll as per the usage, but I get some huge error when I open the packed .exe. Removing the -s didn't do anything.

Not sure if I used it right, what is the proper syntax to use on the command-line?

Comment: I use it like `netz -s -z -w app.exe lib1.dll lib2.dll -so`

Comment: I just tried the above syntax and I got 2 warnings:
     ! Warning: 1001 Cannot process assembly metadata!
     ! Warning: 1005 Cannot process assembly license information!

Apart from that, I think everything went fine but launching the packed .exe doesn't work and shows some exception in a MessageBox.